# Youtube video play button does not work in video iframe in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview, youtube

I am building an article reading android application like TechCrunch.

In the application, the data is parsed by json volley library corresponding like id, article, images and content.

I am loading the content in (html string) in web-view which contains text,images and videos.
The images, Text and video iframe are displaying properly in web-view.

The video iframe loads youtube video that has a default play icon which is not working properly.

The problem is that when I click on that default play icon of youtube the video does not play, but when I click rest on rest of the area of iframe, the video starts playing properly!

Help is appreciated.

Here is my code -

```
String htmldata = "<html><head><style = text/css>      
        img{width:100%!important;height:auto!important;}iframe {width:320px;height:120px;}a {  
        color:#3366CC; text-decoration: none; }</style></head><body style = line-height:25px;  
        >"+c+"</body></html>";            

        web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);               
        web1.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        //web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        //web1.setInitialScale(65);
        web1.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(18);           
        //web1.loadUrl(htmldata);
        web1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        web1.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        web1.loadData(htmldata,"text/html; charset=utf-8",null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem  with youtube mobile player which i had lately .. But there is a temporary solution for that  in which you have to make the player controls hidden like this:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html"  width="100%" height="338" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO-ID?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

in this case we made controls=0

i hope this will help.

Comment: @rhayen thanks this work as I need it. but now the problem is that I am getting url with content that is store in my string and I am loading That String in other html string. so how can i add controls=0 with my url link of iframe that is store in a string variable.